# Animation List simply deosn't start

Tags: android, animation

I'm working on a project which should have a progressdialog. But since i didn't find an easy way to style a progressdialog, i was thinking, that the easiest way is to create a custom dialog class with it's own style, and a frame by frame animation on it, and show it instead. Here is my code:

The xml layout for the dialog:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/loaddialog_animation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/loadanimation"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loaddialog_text"
        style="@style/SmallText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my dialog class:

```
public class LoadDialog extends Dialog
{
    private TextView message;
    ImageView image;
    AnimationDrawable animation;

    public LoadDialog(Context context)
    {
        super(context, R.style.Dialog);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.load_dialog);

        message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loaddialog_text);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loaddialog_animation);
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loadanimation);
        animation = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
    }

    public void setText(String msg)
    {
        message.setText(msg);
    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        super.show();
        animation.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss()
    {
        animation.stop();
        super.dismiss();
    }   
}
```

and the animation resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loadbar_01" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loadbar_02" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loadbar_03" android:duration="50"/>
</animation-list>
```

The problem is that the animation doesn't starts, when i try to show it. I know, there are a lots of topics about this problem, but here are the things, that i have tried:

1. Put the dialogs show() in different parts of my activity: onResume() and onCreate(). 
   onWindowFocusChanged() is not an option, since i want to show a dialog. dialog shown ->focus change, dialog dismissed->focus change ->infinite amount of dialogs shown.
2. I have tried animation.setCallback(image), animation.setVisible(true, true), animation.invalidateSelf() none of them works.
3. I have tried image.post() and put a runnable in there as a parameter, and in the run method starting the animation, no luck.

At this point i'm starting to run out of options. The  I'm only trying to show 3 images changing until the dialog is dismissed. Please if you know, what am i doing wrong, or any alternative, let me know!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry for the misspelling in the title!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change android:oneshot="true" to android:oneshot="false" so that it repeats.  It should be currently only doing one cycle and since your show time is 50, that is really fast.  I would also change that to maybe 200 or so..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/loadbar_01" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/loadbar_02" android:duration="200" />
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/loadbar_03" android:duration="200"/>
 </animation-list>
```

Also, you are setting the image in your xml layout, but animated the background, so you need to either change the xml layout to this:

```
<ImageView         android:id="@+id/loaddialog_animation"         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/loadanimation"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
```

or change you code to get the src file rather than the background, like this:

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loaddialog_animation);
image.set(R.drawable.loadanimation);
animation = (AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();
```

Comment: Thank you, but no luck, still no animation... :(

Comment: Are you seeing the image at all and if so which of the three images do you see?

Comment: Okay, I see something else, but you also need to change the durations to my earlier answer, I will update my answer...

Comment: i see only the first image... no matter how long the duration is. if i use the image.post(runnable) method, then i see the last image on top of the first one...

Comment: Did you try the other changes I added?  It looks like you were animating the backgrond of the ImageView, which would have been blocked by the image set in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue today. Placing the `animation.start()` in the onShow() method of OnShowListener did the trick for me.

```
public class CustomProgressDialog extends Dialog 
{
ImageView progressImage;
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation;

public CustomProgressDialog(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_progress);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    progressImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.custom_progress_image);
    progressImage.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.progress_anim);

    frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) progressImage.getBackground();

    OnShowListener osl = new OnShowListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog)
        {
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    }; 
    setOnShowListener(osl);

    OnDismissListener odl = new OnDismissListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) 
        {
            frameAnimation.stop();
        }
    };
    setOnDismissListener(odl);
}

}
```