# Is it possible to have an animation-list in a dialog?

Tags: android, animation, dialog, android-animation

I created a dialog:

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(myContext, R.style.dialog_loading);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    RelativeLayout contentView = (RelativeLayout) ((Activity) myContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    dialog.show
```

I also tried this:

```
static public Dialog PleaseWait() {
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(myContext, R.style.dialog_loading);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    RelativeLayout contentView = (RelativeLayout) ((Activity) myContext).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading, null);
    dialog.setContentView(contentView);
    ImageView loading=(ImageView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
  loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_loading);
  ((AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground()).start();
    return dialog;
}
```

I also tried this:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(My_Activity.this);
    //Set Background of Dialog - Custom 
    //dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dialogbg);
    //Remove the Title
    dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //Set the View of the Dialog - Custom
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_loading);
    //Set the title of the Dialog
    //dialog.setTitle("Title...");
    ImageView progressSpinner = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.loading);

    //Set the background of the image - In this case an animation (/res/anim folder)
    progressSpinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.anim_loading);
    //Get the image background and attach the AnimationDrawable to it.
    final AnimationDrawable progressAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) progressSpinner.getBackground();
    //Start the animation after the dialog is displayed.
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
    progressAnimation.start();
    }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

The layout xml as follows:

```
           <RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_black"
            android:gravity="center" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:src="@drawable/anim_loading"  />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

And the anim_loading as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading1" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading2" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading3" android:duration="150" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading4" android:duration="150" />
</animation-list>
```

The image shows, but isn't animated. How do I start this animation in a loop?

Comment: Had a similar issue. [Here is the solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19562545/1972597)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            RelativeLayout contentView = (RelativeLayout) ((Activity) this)
                    .getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_loading, null);
            dialog.setContentView(contentView);

            ImageView image = (ImageView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
            final AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);



            dialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                animation.start();
                }
                });
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: If you are doing something similar to AlertDialog, then get the Dialog value by calling create() on the AlertBuilder. Then you can add the method onShowListener

Answer (score 0):

Try start the animation manually

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();
animation.start();
```

Comment: @Diego  try put the drawable into background, not src attribute

Comment: No luck, I guess it has something to do with it being in a dialog

Comment: @Diego I used your layouts and made a simple test http://pastebin.com/DgM3QDPr - after dialog appears, the animation starts

Comment: Weird, I don't get it to work here, and you're using an animation-list as well? I tried it on a device with Android 2.3 and 2.1

Comment: I had to add the listener

Comment: @Diego yes, I used exactly the same XML files you posted in the question. The test application was running on Android 4.1.2, maybe it's behaviour is different on older versions.